# Unexpected errors in MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Could someone explain this to me, what is wrong? Why all these errors?

> Notice: Undefined variable: username in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\general.php
>   on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php
>   on line 6
>
> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line
>   6

Index.php:

```html
<?php
    require 'core/init.php';
?>
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Administraton</title>
    </head>

<body>

<?php
logged_in_redirect();
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username =    $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = '<style>input[type=text], input[type=password] { border: 1px solid red; }</style>';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = '';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = '';
    } else {

        if (strlen($password) > 32) {
            $errors[] = '';
        }
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = '';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location: ./');
            exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = '';
}
if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
<div id="login">
    <p style="position:relative;text-align:center;top:25px;">
        <img src="img/auth.png" alt="Sign in" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#222;border-radius:50%;padding:10px;">
    </p>
    <li style="margin:15px;list-style-type:none;margin-top:75px;">
        <form method="POST" name="login">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Användarnamn">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Lösenord">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%;background-color:#35b3EE;border:none;color:white;" id="myButton" data-loading-text="Loading...">Logga in</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Init.php:

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cms");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
?>
```

Database.php:

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cms");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Users.php:

```html
<?php
// User exists

function user_exists() {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

// Login
function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($username));
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}

// Logged in
function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}

?>
```

General.php:

```html
<?php
// Logged in Session Redirect
function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) {
        header('Location: index');
        exit();
    }
}

// Array Data
function array_sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($item)));
}

// Sanitize Data
function sanitize($data) {
    return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($data)));
}

// Output errors
function output_errors($errors) {
    return '<ul><li><br>' . implode('</li><li><br>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}
?>
```

```html
Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\general.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Overall\Arbete\CMS\core\functions\users.php on line 6
```

Comment: Stop mixing MySQL with MySQLi. The MySQLi errors are probably happening because you are missing the link.

Comment: All the `mysqli_XXX` functions require `$con` as their first argument. This is one of the big differences between mysql and mysqli.

Comment: what a way to end the year, with a very big ***Bang***

Answer (score 0):

In `Users.php` the function below

```
function user_exists() {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Should read:

```
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

and there's a `&` in the `array_sanitize` function.  you might want to remove it.

See if that takes you where you want to go.

Comment: and Script47 is correct.  can't combine the two.  stick with one.

Comment: The `&` is correct -- that function modifies its input, so it takes it by reference.

Comment: Oh, that's new to me.  taking note.  Thanks. didn't know PHP does reference parameters.

Comment: you realize your answer's syntax is incorrect. See what the comments read up there. There is so many things wrong with that, it's not funny. But what a way to end the year huh? With a very big ***BANG!*** ;-)